# Separate log for library and application

Tags: python, logging, aiohttp

In my Python3 application, I use certain packages (like aiohttp, asyncio-redis , etc) , which have logging enabled in them by default. Now when I enable logging in my main application, the logs from aiohttp asyncio-redis are also coming in the log file.

This is what I have done :

```
logging.basicConfig(filename=config['base_dir']+'/../access.log',   
                    level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

And my custom logs are logged like this `logging.debug(message)` . But when  I see the log file , then both package logs and my application logs are present there. How can I have them in different files ? I tried adding 2 loggers , with different file handlers as suggested in many SO threads , but that didn't help really. Infact all i was getting then was empty logs.

So how can I have different logs for the aforementioned scenario ?

**UPDATE:**

Here is my dictConfig :

```
{
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s - %(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'default': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'formatter': 'simple',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': 'debug.log',
            'maxBytes': 1024
        },
        'access': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'formatter': 'simple',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': 'access_log.log',
            'maxBytes': 1024
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'my_logger': {
            'handlers': ['default'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'aiohttp.access': {
            'handlers': ['access'],
            'level': 'INFO'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read the FineManual ? The logging configuration is extensively documented with additional examples, tutorials and even a cookbook. I suggest you start here https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#configuration-dictionary-schema and then look here https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#an-example-dictionary-based-configuration

Comment: Thanks @brunodesthuilliers but that doesn't help with my use case

Comment: Yes it does. Everything you need to know about how to properly configure your logger to avoid mixing library logs with your own app logs is there. You won't get this with `basicConfig`, so first set up a working `dictConfig` and then we can help.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I have setup my dictConfig , now I am getting separate files , but the debug log file is still empty. Updated the post

Comment: Fixed. Working as expected. Thanks @brunodesthuilliers